# Regarding casting in Java within class hierarchies

Tags: java, casting, hierarchy

I am student currently studying for a Computer Science exam and I have a question about casting. Here is a picture of the questions:
[image]

I understand a - c, but I am not sure how to do part d. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. I do not understand how to do this particular question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know what casting is?

Comment: There is a problem with (d). Is that code in a client class? If so, the state variable radius should be marked private.  If it is visible, you need to cast `s` to be of `Sphere` type;  `System.out.println( ((Sphere)s).radius)`;